# Use Javac to compile wrong file in git bash platform,suggesting chinese,but is garbled

Tags: java, javac

I use Javac to compile wrong file such as

```
//Example01.java
public class Example01{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 4;
        byte b = num;
        System.out.println("b="+b);
    }
}
```

I want javac compile like this:
[image]

but the real result is:
[image]

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I really don't understand your question.

Comment: @ShuangLiu No, the second is a minGW terminal, still on windows.

Comment: Try to run javac like this: `LANG=C javac Example01.java`.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos you're right

Comment: please don't include text as images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the top of the MINGW frame and choose [options], then [Text], set [Locale] to zh_CN and [Character set] to GBK, you'll get the screen you want...But why do you want to show it like that ?

Answer (score 0):

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH3mK.png)

I have seen this question on GitBush. The window's options must be updated to display Chinese characters.

Try right clicking on a blank area of the window. From the pop-up menu choose `Options->Text->Locale`, then choose `zh_CN` as the Locale and `GBK` as the character set. Then save the selections. The window should now display Chinese characters correctly.